# If I have two matrices and I want to divide the data and want to keep the same consistency (the Nones stay where they are) in Python?

Tags: python, data-visualization

Data is below:

I want to get:

```
Salaries / Games
```

However, get: TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 SalaryGames = Salary / Games

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'

```
#Salaries
KobeBryant_Salary = [15946875,17718750,19490625,21262500,23034375,24806250,25244493,27849149,None,None]
JoeJohnson_Salary = [12000000,12744189,13488377,14232567,14976754,16324500,18038573,19752645,21466718,23180790]
LeBronJames_Salary = [4621800,5828090,13041250,14410581,15779912,14500000,16022500,17545000,19067500,20644400]
CarmeloAnthony_Salary = [3713640,4694041,13041250,14410581,15779912,17149243,18518574,19450000,22407474,22458000]
DwightHoward_Salary = [4493160,4806720,6061274,13758000,15202590,16647180,18091770,19536360,20513178,21436271]
ChrisBosh_Salary = [3348000,4235220,12455000,14410581,15779912,14500000,16022500,17545000,19067500,20644400]
ChrisPaul_Salary = [3144240,3380160,3615960,4574189,13520500,14940153,16359805,17779458,18668431,20068563]
KevinDurant_Salary = [0,0,4171200,4484040,4796880,6053663,15506632,16669630,17832627,18995624]
DerrickRose_Salary = [0,0,0,4822800,5184480,5546160,None,None,None,None]
DwayneWade_Salary = [3031920,3841443,13041250,14410581,15779912,14200000,15691000,17182000,18673000,15000000]
#Matrix
Salary = np.array([KobeBryant_Salary, JoeJohnson_Salary, LeBronJames_Salary, CarmeloAnthony_Salary, DwightHoward_Salary, ChrisBosh_Salary, ChrisPaul_Salary, KevinDurant_Salary, DerrickRose_Salary, DwayneWade_Salary])

#Games 
KobeBryant_G = [80,77,82,82,73,82,58,78,None,None]
JoeJohnson_G = [82,57,82,79,76,72,60,72,79,80]
LeBronJames_G = [79,78,75,81,76,79,62,76,77,69]
CarmeloAnthony_G = [80,65,77,66,69,77,55,67,77,40]
DwightHoward_G = [82,82,82,79,82,78,54,76,71,41]
ChrisBosh_G = [70,69,67,77,70,77,57,74,79,44]
ChrisPaul_G = [78,64,80,78,45,80,60,70,62,82]
KevinDurant_G = [35,35,80,74,82,78,66,81,81,27]
DerrickRose_G = [40,40,40,81,78,81,None,None,None,None]
DwayneWade_G = [75,51,51,79,77,76,49,69,54,62]
#Matrix
Games = np.array([KobeBryant_G, JoeJohnson_G, LeBronJames_G, CarmeloAnthony_G, DwightHoward_G, ChrisBosh_G, ChrisPaul_G, KevinDurant_G, DerrickRose_G, DwayneWade_G])
```

Comment: It might make more sense to store `0` instead of `None`, for performance reasons. If you want to mask away parts of the computation, define a boolean mask.

Comment: Hi Mateen, nah I appreciate the response.  I want look at data on a graph so when I display it out the outliers don't affect too much.

Answer (score 0):

Change all `None` to `np.nan`. That should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks this was helpful for data visualization.  I didn't want to see data that might skew my graph that the outliers influenced too much.

Answer (score 0):

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1JXdLQvZwkU7Y2wrSM7sLbVlFxBdSHVEq?usp=sharing&fbclid=IwAR1SUEl4_h7Wa8exAlkCUNbOVnDBj3_z73PoqGhIgmsixKDSyPcVyOW04O8

See the graphs at the end.  There's too many injuries and when a number goes from 1000 to 0 it makes the lines get skewed.  Thanks to all the answers!